# how to recover the old data from updated table sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

Hi i wrongly update the data's for all.. I have to retrieve immediately..Is there any option for that? please help me...

**db name: commondatabase**

**table name: candidates**

I tried following code,

```
    Select [PAGE ID],[Slot ID],[AllocUnitId],[Transaction ID] ,[RowLog Contents 0]
, [RowLog Contents 1],[RowLog Contents 3],[RowLog Contents 4] ,[Log Record]
FROM    sys.fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)   
WHERE AllocUnitId IN 
(Select [Allocation_unit_id] from sys.allocation_units allocunits 
INNER JOIN sys.partitions partitions ON (allocunits.type IN (1, 3)   
AND partitions.hobt_id = allocunits.container_id) 
OR (allocunits.type = 2 AND partitions.partition_id = allocunits.container_id)   
Where object_id=object_ID('' + 'dbo.student' + '')) 
AND Operation in ('LOP_MODIFY_ROW','LOP_MODIFY_COLUMNS')  
And [Context] IN   ('LCX_HEAP','LCX_CLUSTERED')
```

i don't know how to use htis?

If any chances for do that it will help me.. i don't know what will do this situation

Comment: how? can you help me.. i am struggling toomuch..

Comment: @marc_s well, you could play-back the transaction logs to a recovery database and stop playback just before the bad UPDATE was sent.